# Show differences between two data sets using a unique identifier through VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, macros, comparison

I have researched this extensively but cannot seem to find a solution. I am attempting to create a macro that will compare data between two tables on different sheets and highlight differences using a unique identifier.

Here is an example:

**Sheet 1 (Data Set 1)**

```
UniqueID | Name |  Date  |  Status
----------------------------------------
| 1230 | Bob   | 1/1/2016  | Denied    
| 6985 | Mike  | 1/6/2016  | Pending    
| 4442 | Will  | 1/9/2016  |  Approved
```

**Sheet 2 (Data Set 2)**

```
UniqueID | Name |  Date  |  Status
----------------------------------------
| 1230 | Bob   | 1/1/2016  | Denied    
| 6985 | Mike  | 1/6/2016  | Approved    
| 4442 | Will  | 2/27/2016 |  Approved
```

In this case, the macro would use the shared Unique ID and field name between the data sets and determine the two changes: one to a status field and one to a date field.

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: Do you need VBA? I believe you could do this with Conditional Formatting, or at least with a new helper sheet (where you compare columns, and show any differences).  So, you'd like Mike's status in `Sheet1 DataSet1` to be highlighted, yes? Since it's not "Pending" as it in in the top example?

Comment: hi! yes, I need to use VBA for this. Initially the data set was small enough that I could use a helper column or two combined with conditional formatting. Since then it has grown and now contains 50+ fields that all need to be monitored for changes. Also I realized I meant to change the name of the second data set to Sheet 2 (Data Set 2), my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

if, as per you example, your data sets have UniqueID columns matching each other then you can code like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main1()
    Dim ds1 As Range, ds2 As Range, row As Range, col As Range, f As Range

    Set ds1 = Worksheets("DataSet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| change "DataSet1" to your actual "Data Set 1" sheet name
    Set ds2 = Worksheets("DataSet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| change "DataSet2" to your actual "Data Set 2" sheet name

    For Each row In ds1.Columns(1).Cells '<--| loop through "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" values (in its column 1)
        For Each col In ds1.Rows(row.row).Cells '<--| ...loop through "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" row cells...
            If col.Value <> ds2(col.row, col.Column) Then '<--| ... if current cell value doesn't match corresponding "Data Set 2" one, then ...
                col.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<--| ...mark "Data Set 1" current cell...
                ds2(col.row, col.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<--| ...mark corresponding "Data Set 2" one
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```

otherwise, you must find first find `Data Set 1` "UniqueID" corresponding cell in `Data Set 2` 1st column, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim ds1 As Range, ds2 As Range, row As Range, col As Range, f As Range

    Set ds1 = Worksheets("DataSet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| change "DataSet1" to your actual "Data Set 1" sheet name
    Set ds2 = Worksheets("DataSet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| change "DataSet2" to your actual "Data Set 2" sheet name

    For Each row In ds1.Columns(1).Cells '<--| loop through "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" values (in its column 1)
        Set f = ds2.Columns(1).Find(what:=row.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| look for current UniqueID in "Data Set 2" column 1
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<-- if "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" found in "Data Set 2", then...
            For Each col In ds1.Rows(row.row).Cells '<--| ...loop through "Data Set 1" "UniqueID" row cells...
                If col.Value <> ds2(col.row, col.Column) Then '<--| ... if current cell value doesn't match corresponding "Data Set 2" one, then ...
                    col.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<--| ...mark "Data Set 1" current cell...
                    ds2(col.row, col.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<--| ...mark corresponding "Data Set 2" one
                End If
            Next col
        End If
    Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a VBA solution, then

if the data set 1 is in sheet `Sheet1` and data set 2 in sheet `Sheet2` then the below code will highlight the differences in red color.

```
Sub foo()

For i = 2 To 50 'considering 50 rows in Sheet1
    For j = 2 To 50 'considering 50 rows in Sheet2
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            For k = 1 To 4
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, k).Value <> Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, k).Value Then
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, k).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't use a solution that relies on cell location because the records will be in a different order each date the macro is run. Because of this I was looking for a solution that uses the unique id and field name. In this case, the macro would find Mike's status change because in data set 6985, Status = "Pending" and in data set 2 6985, Status = "Approved"

Comment: this code checks the differences based on the unique id. so it will work even if the order is different. i have tested and it works

Comment: @ArunThomas You should not loop cells directly it to find a value. `Application.Match()` will be MUCH faster for this case. Also, you should use `Exit For` at cases like this where only one match will be. There is no need to loop after you have found that match. Still one thing bothers me: why `For k = 1 To 4`? You will start that loop only if `Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1)`. This way nothing will ever happen if `k` is 1. Apart from this, the answer is pretty solid and easy to understand. ;)

Comment: @Dirk Reichel, thank you for the suggestions. i will keep these in mind when facing a similar situation next time. And `For k = 1 To 4` was put to loop through all the four columns in a row and mark only the specific columns which has the difference

Answer (score 0):

Just conditional formatting will do it for you like this:

```
=B2<>INDEX(H$2:H$4,MATCH($A2,$G$2:$G$4,0))
```

You will need to change the ranges according to your sheets.
The layout I used was looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try out this code below.

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)  
Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As     String
Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
Dim row As Long, col As Integer
Set report = Workbooks.Add
With ws1.UsedRange
ws1row = .Rows.Count
ws1col = .Columns.Count
End With
With ws2.UsedRange
ws2row = .Rows.Count
ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With
maxrow = ws1row
maxcol = ws1col
If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col
difference = 0
For col = 1 To maxcol
  For row = 1 To maxrow
  colval1 = ""
  colval2 = ""
  colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
  colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula
  If colval1 <> colval2 Then
 difference = difference + 1
 Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2
 Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
 Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
 Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
  End If
Next row
Next col
Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
report.Saved = True
If difference = 0 Then
report.Close False
End If
Set report = Nothing
MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation,     "Comparing Two Worksheets"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Compare2WorkSheets Worksheets("Sheet1"), Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set myWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\familycomputerclub-website\Excel2007        \testcompare2.xlsx")
Compare2WorkSheets Workbooks("testcompare1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1"),         myWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```